# How to handle boundary conditions that are piece wise functions

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Consider the PDE
$$u_{t} = k u_{xx}$$

subject to the conditions
$$u(0, t) = 0, u(L, t) = 0$$

and

$$u(x, 0) = \begin{cases} 1, 0 < x < \frac{L}{2} \\ 0, \frac{L}{2} < x < L  \end{cases}$$

my issue comes in when handling the piece-wise function. how to I do that. I used separation of variables to get to this equation:

$$u(x,y) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} A_{n}sin(\frac{n \pi}{L}x) e^{-k (\frac{n \pi}{L})^{2}t}$$

from here how do I proceed?

Answer (score 1):

Using the given expression,

$$u(x,0) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty A_n \sin \left( \frac{n\pi x}{L}\right)$$

and recall that the Fourier coefficients are given by

$$A_n = \frac{2}{L}\int^L_0 u(x,0) \times \sin \left( \frac{n\pi x}{L}\right) dx .$$

Now, you can use the given piecewise initial condition to evaluate the Fourier coefficients:

$$A_n = \frac{2}{L}\int^{L/2}_0 \sin \left( \frac{n\pi x}{L}\right) dx$$

and I think you can continue from here.

Comment: Oh ok i see thanks. where does the 2 come from though. I'm getting 1/L

Comment: It comes from how you derive the Fourier coefficients for a Fourier Sine series on $[0,L]$. An easy way to check this is that if you consider the Fourier Series of $\sin \left( \frac{\pi x}{L} \right)$, then $A_1 = 1$ and the rest of the $A_n$'s must be $0$. Here, $1 = A_1 = C \int^L_0 \sin \left( \frac{\pi x}{L} \right)^2 dx = \frac{CL}{2}$, thus giving $C = \frac{2}{L}$.